# Loaded pickled dataframes can't be concatenated

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pickle

I've used `pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)` in the past with no problem, but I am currently having a problem.

I have a set of pickled dataframes, and I put them in a list like this:

```
pickle_frames = [pickle.load(open(pickle_file, 'rb')) for pickle_file in pickles_list]
```

edit: also tried this in a `for` loop instead of the comprehension like so, just in case, but with the same result:

```
pickle_frames = []
for pickle_file in pickles_list:
    this_pickle = pickle.load( open(pickle_file, 'rb'))
    pickle_frames.append(this_pickle)
```

edit: I also tried casting the loaded pickles as numpy arrays like so, again with the same result:

```
pickle_frames = [np.array(pickle.load( open(pickle_file, 'rb'))) for pickle_file in pickles_list]
```

Then I try to concatenate:

`df = pd.concat(pickle_frames, keys=pickles_list`)

And get this error:

`TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object`

I've tested the list of frames and it looks fine; `type(pickle_frames)` returns `list` and `type(pickle_frames[0])` returns `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` ... I can load and perform other DataFrame operations on `pickle_frames[i]` for any `i`.

Any ideas as to why `concat` isn't recognizing the loaded, previously pickled dataframes, when they seem to be perfectly good?

=======================

Full code:

```
import pickle, os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = os.getcwd()

pickles_list = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if  f.endswith('.p')]
pickle_frames = [pd.DataFrame(pickle.load(open(pickle_file, 'rb')) for pickle_file in pickles_list]
df = pd.concat(pickle_frames, keys=pickles_list)
```

Comment: Do you know if your current version of pandas matches the version with which the frames were written?

Comment: @mdurant Yes; I made and pickled the frames about an hour ago.

Comment: how did you pickle the objects, did you use `pd.DataFrame.to_pickle`?

Comment: No, @qwwqwwq, I didn't even know that existed! Thanks for the pointer! I added a question and answer about this that I hope might be helpful for others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754658/whats-the-fastest-way-to-pickle-a-pandas-dataframe/28754659#28754659

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that one of the frames was not properly formatted (I included it accidentally from an earlier batch of pickles). The type was still `pandas.core.frameDataFrame` though, so I'm still not sure why I got this exact error. Thanks for your question, @mdurant, it helped lead me to find the problem.