# What's the fastest way to pickle a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

Which is better, using Pandas built-in method or `pickle.dump`?

The standard pickle method looks like this:

```
pickle.dump(my_dataframe, open('test_pickle.p', 'wb'))
```

The Pandas built-in method looks like this:

```
my_dataframe.to_pickle('test_pickle.p')
```

Comment: why not just benchmark them?

Comment: @tolanj What exactly do you mean by benchmark? I include timings in the answer below.

Comment: For those needing a nice benchmark for `panda.DataFrame` serialization : [FastSerialization](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/03/16/Fast-Serialization).

Comment: The first method is more generic: Imagine you have your own custom filesystem and your own library for opening files in it. In that case `my_dataframe.to_pickle('my/weird/path')` would not work while `pickle.dump(my_dataframe, my_weird_fs.open('/my/weird/path', 'wb'))` would work fine.

Answer (score 21):

Thanks to @qwwqwwq I discovered that pandas has a built-in `to_pickle` method for dataframes. I did a quick time test:

```
In [1]: %timeit pickle.dump(df, open('test_pickle.p', 'wb'))
10 loops, best of 3: 91.8 ms per loop

In [2]: %timeit df.to_pickle('testpickle.p')
10 loops, best of 3: 88 ms per loop
```

So it seems that the built-in is only narrowly better (to me, this is useful because it means it's probably not worth refactoring code to use the built-in) - hope this helps someone!

Comment: Why are you concerned about processing time?  I would think functionality was more important.  Does `to_pickle` have any extra functionality?  Is it just the convenience of not having to import pickle?

Comment: This is way late, but just to chime in: it appears that for very large dataframes, the write time (`pickle.dump` or `df.to_pickle`) is about the same regardless of method, but read time is _much_ faster for files created with `df.to_pickle`. 

With `timeit` on a dataframe of size 53330 rows x 21 columns, it's 115 ms to unpickle a file written with `pickle.dump` and only 3 ms to unpickle a file written with `df.to_pickle`. Not sure where the huge speedup comes from, but it's quite noticeable.

Comment: Thanks for the addition Tasha, very helpful. Really curious why the speed difference exists, I would have thought they should both have resulted in the same file.

Answer (score 3):

Easy benchmark, right?

[image]

Not difference at all, in fact I expect that Pandas implements [**getstate**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) so that calling `pickle.dump(df)` is actually the same as calling `df.to_pickle()`.

If you search for example `__getstate__` on the Pandas source code, you will find [that it is implemented on several objects](https://github.com/search?l=&q=__getstate__%20repo%3Apandas-dev%2Fpandas&type=Code).